# Is there anywhere that I can find the full tracklist of an album without any other info?

Tags: album

I have a spreadsheet where I mathematically rank my favorite albums. Each track has a score associated with it. Is there any website that lists each track in a fashion that enables me to copy and paste it into my spreadsheet, so that I don't have to type in the name of each song?

Here's an example:

[image]

As you can see, typing out all the song names for every single album wastes a considerable amount of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to the album's page at [Discogs](https://www.discogs.com) and copy and paste the track listing into your spreadsheet (this works at least with Libreoffice).
A more advanced way of doing this would be to write a Python program to scrape the site using the [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc) library.

Comment: When I try to copy-paste from discogs I get the duration of each song too

Comment: You can add a dummy column for the durations and then delete it. The same for listings that have track numbers.